# TFS2013 Auto build and publish

Tags: build, msbuild, tfsbuild, release-management

Actually, I was working with manual build and release concept and Now I have to start the automation with TFS2013, so Please suggest how to start the Build automation with TFS2013, I am getting confused while the merging from a development branch to QA branch.

Answer (score 0):

XAML builds are deprecated. We strongly recommend that you upgrade TFS2013 and migrate to the new build system as explained in this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/migrate-from-xaml-builds?view=azure-devops).

However, if you have to use TFS2013, then to enable XAML builds you must **connect a XAML build controller** to your collection. See [Configure and manage your build system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ms252495(v=vs.120)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

You could also customize your XAML templates or added custom tasks as your requirement.

If you want a step by step build/deploy process and tutorial, I would suggest you take a look at this wonderful blog-- **[Automated Web Deployment and Team Build Using TFS 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/automated-web-deployment-and-team-build-using-tfs-2013/)**